# window.print disables the parent window

Tags: javascript

I am having a requirement to print a html dump sent from backend system. This print is triggered on button click from the UI. I am using window.print as shown below. The problem here is, while the print preview is loading, it shouldn't stop the user from performing actions in the parent window. However when window.print is used even on a new window, the parent window is frozen and disabled. Is there a way to enable the user access in the parent window?

Below code is used for the print:

```
function printElem(elem){
                var newwindow = window.open('', 'PRINT');
        newwindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + 
                document.title + '</title>');
        newwindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        newwindow.document.write(elem);
        newwindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                newwindow.focus();
                newwindow.print();
                newwindow.close();
 }
```

Comment: your best bet is to setup a print route on the `back-end` that deals with printing the dumb data, the `print()` method opens a Modal window meaning it will block the user from going back to the original window like an alert window

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Button').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

add this code before print window opened(`var newwindow = window.open('', 'PRINT');`)

Comment: You've misunderstood the question, the goal is "_it shouldn't stop the user from performing actions_".

Comment: you want to work some another function on parent window while open the print window?